# Check if url to photo is within user's current photos

Tags: arrays, facebook, algorithm, comparison, photo

I got a link to a photo from facebook. Supposing that an user might have deleted part of his/her photos, but the link still exists (the `url`s are still valid for 30 days), I would like to check if the user still has the photo posted. *I would like to do this* **only** *for photos posted by the user using the app*, not for photos the user is tagged in.

One approach, I think, would be to get all the links to photos at the time of checking, and to verify if any of the photos has the same link with saved link(s) the photo(s). Basically, getting an array with the joint elements of two arrays (ones that are compared).

Is this a good approach, or would there be a better one? Should this approach work?

Comment: i think you can try to check the response you get via url if it is some error or a 404 then photo not exists otherwise it is there

Comment: No.. As I wrote  (maybe not explicitly enough), the url will be still valid 30 days after a photo is deleted. So what I want is to check if the photo from the url still exists within the user's photo. Check if it was not deleted